# The Granger causality test Python - sm.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-analysis, multivariate-testing

What does it mean when python outputs "The Granger causality test statistic cannot be compute because the VAR has a perfect fit of the data."

Answer (score 0):

It means two series x(t) and y(t) to establish Granger causality are identical or any one of the OLS fits for them gives numerically not acceptable statistics, i.e., TSS or RSS,
See the code [exception](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/af6ac164f74766c74605e02b7834295c8563dd53/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py#L1586)